# Apache solr search for multiple fields without specifying field name

Tags: solr, solr7

Apache solr search for multiple fields without specifying field name in solr 7.7.2 version. Created copy field for all fields and assigning it to dest=“text” which is field of text type. But it doesn’t give any output. It works for only one field where df=fieldName.

It has managed schema which automatically override the changes after indexing, please let me know what would be the issue.

Comment: What's your query when you don't get any results? Does it work with `df=text`? How is the field actually defined?

Comment: Thanks for reply, my q=Name:Mayur works fine, And I have set df=Name, so q=Mayur also works fine. But for searching for multiple fields I have created <copyField source=“Name” dest=“text”/>  <copyField source=“Region” dest=“text”/> where I have created text field <field Name=“text” type=“text_general” indexed=“true” stored=“false” multivalued=“true”/> I have done this changes before indexing data. After data index this changes are overridden and replaced with <copyField source=“Name” dest=“Name_str”/>  <copyField source=“Region” dest=“Region_str”/> and df=“text” doesn’t give any output.